# Can you make a button using the tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a button using the Tkinter canvas. But I can't find anything on how to do it. I've tried using the regular button widget, but those don't display nor do anything. If anyone has a way of doing, please tell me!

Comment: What exactly do you want? A button inside canvas? Or using canvas to simulate a button?

Comment: When you say "make a button using the Tkinter canvas", do you mean you want to create a custom button by drawing the borders and defining all of the key bindings and behaviors yourself? Or, are you asking how to add a standard `Button` to a canvas?

Comment: I mean I want to draw all the stuff and do all that on my own. Also, is it possible to use an image as what you click on?

Comment: Yes, all that is possible. Why did you add `[ANSWERED]` to the title? It doesn't appear that you've accepted any of the answers.

Comment: on another post some guy told be how to add buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1+w, y1+h, fill=fill, tags=tag, width=width)
canvas.tag_bind(tag, "<Button-1>", function)
```

2nd line is key :)

Answer (score -1):

This generates a button on a canvas, the canvas setting should be changeable without changing the button. Found here https://python-tricks.com/button-in-tkinter/

```
import tkinter as tk
screen = tk.Tk()

#Screen size
screen.geometry('300x300')

#Button
button_tk = tk.Button(screen, text="Hello") 

button_tk.pack(side='top')

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: The question specifically asks about using a `Canvas`, but your answer doesn't use a `Canvas`.